# How to add more points/dots on an existing pairs plot?

Tags: r

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
Trigen <- data.frame(OTriathlon$Gender,OTriathlon$Swim,OTriathlon$Bike,OTriathlon$Run)
colnames(Trigen) <- c("Gender","Swim","Bike","Run")
res <- split(Trigen[,2:4],Trigen$Gender)
pairs(res$Male, pch="M", col = 4)
points(res$Female, pch ="F", col= 2)
```

Basically, Customize the pairs plot, so where the plot symbol and color of each data point represents
gender.
I did some random things in the code but the issue that I am facing is that I cant add female points to the existing plot. After running the points code it just stays the same doesn't get updated

Comment: You should use a dataset that's available to everyone, or include your `OTriathlon` dataset in the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call *points* sevral times, because you can use the factor directly as a color. Example:

```
plot(iris[,c(2,3)], col=iris$Species)
```